# Is it possible to animate a statue?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology

Could one construct a statue out of materials that could be made to move in controlled or semi-controlled ways? The question is essentially can one make a robot without the internal mechanics? I'm thinking about materials that would generate motion in reaction to electrical current or focused chemical reactions.

Comment: Does this have to be internally contained, or can something external move it (IE soft clay statue with magnets inside it that are manipulated by magnets outside the statue in the surroundings)

Comment: What do you mean by "internal mechanics", can you clarify that part?

Comment: Something that can be made to move in semi-controlled ways without internal mechanics... like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marionette)?

Comment: How about a marionette.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost exactly related to the study of Flexible Robotics, which is an ongoing effort at the PhD level.

As a note, there will always be internal mechanics.  Even the human body relies on the internal mechanics of the skeleton.  However, with flexible robotics, you have more opportunities to put the structure, sensors, and effectors in the skin of the object, rather than being forced to always tie them to some internal metal structure.  Flexible robotics let you use the inherent qualities of the material more readily than other forms of robotics.

Answer (score 3):

The stuff you may be after exists in Iain M Banks' culture novels and is mentioned in Look to Windward. EDust (Everything Dust) was designed as the ultimate building material and is constituted of a swarm of tiny machines which, I presume, have a distributed processing ability. The material itself seems to be a uniform consistency but can be programmed to self assemble into any shape including that of an animated figure, in [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vKtwMsVqaiEC&lpg=PT311&ots=aub_f4Nltm&dq=iain%20m%20banks%20ultimate%20building%20material&pg=PT311#v=onepage&q=iain%20m%20banks%20ultimate%20building%20material&f=false) case an assassin who kills by flowing into the victims body cavities and rupturing them from the inside. Which is nice.

Of course when I say exists, I mean has been made up. But call me optimistic, a swarm of nanobots is not too much of a stretch of existing technology.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of cloth that reacts to an electric charge?  I've seen a few different things but here is one that you could look at.  http://hackaday.com/2011/07/01/electro-active-polymers/

it changes shape when a charge is applied and relaxes when removed, just like a muscle.  a well designed statue could be controlled by wise placement of the fabric and no actual motors.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this is basically how animals work (I'm including humans in that).

So what you need is:

1. An internal skeletal structure.  This can be made out of anything rigid that will stand up to the use you need.
2. Materials that contract or expand in a controlled manner based on an electrical charge or a chemical to act as your muscles.
3. Since your "muscles" don't need blood, we can skip the whole blood/food/oxygen parts.  So next you need a nervous system - some way to transmit signals to the appropriate muscles.
4. After that you need a brain.  Technically this might be part of the nervous system, but I wanted to call it out separately.  This doesn't need to be a human - or thinking - brain, but it would need to be a very advanced computer to handle coordinating the muscles in such a way that the body moves like you'd expect it too.
5. Your robot needs some way to avoid walking into walls, falling over, or hitting you instead of your enemies.  So sensors.
6. Communication - this could be anything from voice command to an XBOX controller with pre-set moves that lets you control your robot like its in a fighter game, but you need some way to tell it which actions to take.
7. Some sort of power source for the brain/nervous system/sensors/communication.  Could be batteries, a generator off fuel, solar panels, etc - but you need something.

If the above counts as internal workings, I think you're out of luck - I don't see how you can get around the above in a science setting.  You could likely make the statue without a skeletal structure and use other muscles in place, but I don't think it would move - or look - like anything natural.

Comment: This is a good answer...except that it explicitly says "like a robot but without the internal workings" whereas you list the internal workings...

Comment: @TimB - It says internal mechanics, that needs a bit of clarification. Otherwise you end up with B.O.B. from Monsters vs. Aliens.

Comment: I was trying to just list the bare minimum - I assumed internal workings meant things like actual motors, pipelines for lubricant/coolant, etc.  I'll adjust the answer somewhat to clarify.